# Jenkins - Dir into another job's workspace to execute script

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have a pipeline that builds two Jenkins in parallel:

```
  try {
    parallel (
      a: {
        script { build_a = build(job: "...", parameters: [...]) }
      },
      b: {
        script { build_b = build(job: "...", parameters: [...]) }
      },
    )
  }
```

The two jobs will do a full checkout of several repos, and then build. If both succeed I want to tag the HEAD of all those repos.
For that I would need to go to both build_a and build_b 's workspace and execute the git tag commands from there.
Is this possible?

Alternatively, I would need to do an added two full checkouts in the parent job in order to tag them after the two jobs succeed.

I tried looking in the documentation but it doesn't seem possible.

Comment: Not exactly what you are asking about, but if you have a local git mirror you can checkout with that mirror really fast, and "two full checkouts" won't be an issue.

Comment: As long as you don't clean the job workspace, what is stopping your from simply using `dir('$JENKINS_HOME/jobs/<name_of_job>')` and getting into the workspace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, you can't assume that the workspaces persist after the jobs have completed. That's why Jenkins doesn't have any commands for accessing them. Can you do an API call to create a tag? GitHub has an [API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/git/tags?apiVersion=2022-11-28#create-a-tag-object) for that, I'm sure other providers do too.